# A quick question about the definition of adjoint, category theory.

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, definition

I am pretty new to fundamental terms of the category theory.

My textbook says that adjoint is:

> $\mathbb{B}(F(A), B) \cong \mathbb{A}(A, G(B))$ ... obeying certain rules (which I skip).

Do I understand correctly: it requires a bijection between two sets of morphisms?

Comment: Yes, a bijection of those two sets, but the "certain rules" are really, really important.

Comment: Also, did you inadvertently switch $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$?

Comment: @Randall, that was I mistype. I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: I figured as much.  It is easy to do.

Comment: When the categories are both posets, an adjunction simplifies to:
`∀a,b. f a ≤ b ⇔ a ≤ g b`. These are then called Galois Connections ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For two functors to be adjoint we require a bijection between those two sets of morphisms which obey those "certain rules", for each $A\in \Bbb A$ and each $B\in \Bbb B$.